# The method or operation is not implemented error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent-api

Quando vou fazer a adição de um registro na minha tela Incluir, me aparece esse erro.

O que pode ser?

**Service**

```
public void AddItem(Test item)
        {

            var codigos = this.context.Tests.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Codigo == item.Codigo);
            if (codigos != null)
            {
                this.context.Testes.Any(x =>
                x.Id == codigos.Id
                && x.Codigo != item.Codigo);
                throw new ValidationException("Codigo", Resources.TestesResources.ErroUniqueKeyCodigo);
            }
            else
            {
                base.context.Tests.Add(item);
                base.Save();

            }

        }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Incluir([ModelBinder(typeof(CollectionModelBinder))]Testitem)
        {
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                item.Id = this.Id;
                item.Value = DateTime.Now;
                item.Use = User;
                try
                {                    
                    this.Service.AddItem(item);
                    return this.SuccessView(true);
                }
                catch (ValidationException exception)
                {
                    base.AddValidationErrors(exception);
                    return base.PartialView(item);
                }
            }
            else
                return base.PartialView(item);
        }
```

**Erro**

[image: Foto do Erro]

Comment: Você consegue debugar e dizer exatamente em que linha dá o erro ?

Comment: Coloquei alguns breakpoints no código ele nem cai nos metódos, quando debuga.

Comment: Nesse screenshot, deixas-te a parte mais importante de fora: a stack trace. Põe a stack trace aqui, e coloca o código relevante, onde a excepção foi lançada.

Comment: Posta o código de ValidationException, por favor

Answer (score 2):

Muito provavelmente você utilizou geradores de código onde geram métodos no seguinte formato:

```
void MeuNovoMetodo () {
    throw new NotImplementedException ();
}
```

Eles fazem isso para que seu código possa compilar mas que você não se esqueça de implementar ele depois. Você só vai descobrir qual método esqueceu de implementar olhando a stack trace, ou pesquisando nos arquivos pela NotImplementedException exception.